# How to add third party java libraries to java

Tags: java, classpath

Here is a third party library that I want to use.
https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core

I want to use the library in my project.

How do I install or add the library to my class path, so I can run my code via the command line without any problems.

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.encog/encog-core

Comment: You should use Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Read the docs for Maven or Gradle, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.3.0:

- Go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.encog/encog-core as mentioned above.
- Click download JAR.
- Copy the downloaded .jar file in to `WEB-INF/lib` folder in your project.
- Right click on this .jar file -> build path -> add to build path (If you have eclipse, other wise, Google in your IDE documentations)

If you need the 3.4.0, you will need maven.

Comment: What if we don't have an ide? whatever that is... what if we are using cat, head, tail, tr and sed with unix pipes to edit documents?